# On Drop target enter and leave custom event

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop, custom-controls

I have one drop target div which have some nested div's, i add dragover event to parent div and add 'drag-allow' attrib to nested divs. I want to add custom event fires when mouse enters or leave any child div.

```
<div id="container">
   <div id="page1" drag-allow >
    Page #1
   </div>
   <div id="page2" drag-allow>
    Page #2
   </div>
   <div id="page3" drag-allow>
    Page #3
   </div>
```

```
    var ground = document.getElementById('container');
...
ground.addEventListener('dragover', function(e){
    evt.preventDefault();
    evt.stopPropagation();

    evt.target.id; // custom event will fire based on child div's id

}, false);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add two more events like

```
    ground.addEventListener('dragenter', function(e){
    if(e.target.nodeType == Node.ELEMENT_NODE && e.target.hasAttribute('drag-allow')){
        // this will check drop area is div and must have attribute drag-allow
        console.log(e.target);
    }
}, false);

ground.addEventListener('dragleave', function(e){
    // on leave event fires on every nested div like above event
}, false);
```